# How can Windows 10 become de-activated

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I bought a Windows 10 Home edition laptop with Windows and Microsoft Office 19 already installed and activated it. I setup a non-priviledged user account and gave the default account a strong password which I kept to myself. I also installed iDrive but didn't set it up. I gave the computer to a niece a year or two ago and heard no more about it.

Was it properly activated? I believe so. In the settings pages, for example the page that deals with users, it now says something like "To personalize the computer you must activate Windows". I did various personalizations before I gave it to my niece, for example adding the user account. I seem to remember that it is clear when it has been activated - there's no doubt involved. I've installed Windows many times over the last few decades from NT up to 10, so I'd hope not to have screwed up :-)

On a visit the other day I had brief access to the computer and found that Windows was not activated. Office 19 was listed as installed in the list of installed programs but I couldn't find the relevant directories on the hard disk. The iDrive directory was still present.

How can a computer go from activated to not activated in this manner? My niece lives in the wilds of Ecuador and uses a local guy who fixes things and I'm thinking that lacking the admin password he broke in somehow. But how would that happen. With physical access, can he have stolen the original Windows license from the installation?

Edited again:
Do Windows 10 installations have a system recovery partition? I'm a Linux/Mac user so I don't have a Win10 machine to check on. If someone used that to get around not having the admin password, would that de-activate?

Also I noticed that an antivirus program was running but I didn't install it - I setup the Windows Defender.

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 are we dealing with?  If this was an Enterprise installation, it requires the machine to communicate with a KMS every 90 days.  The only other explanation is that the machine was never actually properly activated.  If you can clarify those points, feel free to [edit] your question, instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @WilliamMorris Theoretically, hardware changes (more likely) or a Windows update (much less likely) could trigger Windows deactivation. Regarding original installation, note that it is also *technically* possible (at least with 21H1 Home [May 2021], booting directly from media) to skip setting up an internet connection and have customization work (temporarily). But I honestly don't know if something like that would apply here.

Comment: Thanks @Anaksunaman - I don't think I had installation media. The shop installed Windows and Office (I edited the post to correct that). Hardware change seems unlikely (on a laptop used by a teacher training student).

Comment: Have they installed the same version? I mean not the same build but Home, Pro, etc. If not the license isn't valid and it won't activate.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I didn't notice. I only had transient access and no longer have.

Comment: @Anaksunaman - A Windows Update will **never** cause Windows to become deactivated.  Additionally, only a motherboard change would cause Windows to become deactivated.

Comment: @Ramhound Wasn't there a Windows update back in the day on older versions of Windows that once applied, it deactivated pirated copies of activated or cracked/hacked activated Windows OS? I vaguely recall something but it was so long ago; maybe XP.

Comment: @PillsburyITDoughboy - You mean Windows SP2 (SP 1?) which introduced the module that handled Windows activation? Alright; Sure; Technically that was distributed through Windows Update, but that was not the case being described, Windows was reinstalled by a store (apparently) and the wrong edition was installed.  We’re not talking about Windows XP; Windows 10 uses a digital entitlement;

Comment: @Ramhound Yah, probably so... you're right, definitely not the case here but only technically perhaps in general. Those darn technicalities... Thank you!

Comment: I just don’t want completely off the wall explanations being submitted as a comment.  Windows Update and a hardware change is not the reason Windows(in this case) wasn’t activated

Answer (score -1):

As I suspected, it is easy to get around the admin password with physical access. One option is to boot in Safe Mode with a CMD prompt and then "net user administrator /active:yes" to activate a hidden admin account.

Then it seems that there's ways to extract the clear text product keys, for example from the registry or the bios. Daft but apparently true.

So to answer the original question,

```
With physical access, can he have stolen the 
original Windows license from the installation?
```

Getting root access is straightforward, and extracting the product key for use on another computer is also easy. To use the extracted key, he'd need to deactivate the license on this computer. If it's an OEM license (which it probably was, as it came installed on the computer) he might not be able to use it, but that's another question.

Comment: Extracting the license is unnecessary.  Why was this submitted as an answer to your question, it certainly for answer the question, “how can Windows become deactivated?”

Comment: @Ramhound I assumed that extracting the license was the point. Edited my answer a bit to clarify.

Comment: Any version of Windows with the license stored in the ACPI table can automatically detect that license when it's being installed.  Windows 10 uses a digital entitlement so it's never necessary to even enter the license key when it's stored in the ACPI table.